# Android Activities Stack - UP button method ideas

Tags: android

I have `Activity A` (Main) and `Activity B`.

Fact: Activity A has: `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

Usual scenario is:

1. User launches application > `Activity A`.
2. User clicks an item > `Activity B`

   3.A. If user clicks on back/up buttons > Back to `A` (**without calling finish() on B**)

   - User clicks the SAME item as before > Forth to `B`.
   - At this point he can go back and forth without new instances. It's all in the stack and it doesn't recreate activities. (All right!)

   [image]

   3.B. If user clicks Home, then goes to task manager and brings the app to front > `Activity B` (all good, so far)

   - If user clicks UP button, it goes to TASK MANAGER, and I want it to go to `Activity A` (back button is expected to work this way, so let's focus on UP button).

Here's the implementation I have in `Activity B` for BACK and UP buttons.

```
@Override   
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    // I don't want to finish() the activity, so the user can reclick the same
    // item without reloading the whole activity again (webview slow when parsing html).
    return;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            // I don't want to finish() the activity... idem.
            // I need to implement here the bring Activity A to front
        break;
    }
}
```

So, what I want is: **to "Go Back" to `Activity A` keeping the same idea of using the stack to reload Activity B if needed, without using Intents (unless it calls activity to front, without adding items to the stack.)**

Let me know if I explained myself clearly and if you need more info.

Comment: C'mon, people. I need your juicy brains! (I'm not a Zombie, FYI)